# wicket DropDownChoice No get method defined for class

Tags: wicket

I am using a DropDownChoice, its key and value are username property of User object. But when I submit I get the following error No get method defined for class: class java.lang.String expression: username.

When the form is submitted, I want the form input to be set onto name property of the SearchPerson object, I am loading the dropdown using the users(list of user). My select box's display and value are both username

```
<select name="select" wicket:id="name" id="select">
                    <option value="test">test</option>
                </select>

form.add(new DropDownChoice("name",new PropertyModel(searchPerson, "name"),users,new ChoiceRenderer( "username", "username" )));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to inject an `User` into a `String` property (`searchPerson.name`). Either make `users` a `List<Strings>`, or make the DropDownChoice have a `IModel<User>`.

[edited]

And, that error probably is happening because the component is trying to get the current model value's key property. So, it takes `searchPerson.name` and try to get the value of the property `username` from it, which obviously doesn't exist, since it's a `String`, not an `User`.

**[updated]**

If what you want is auto-complete of a text field, you could try `DefaultCssAutocompleteTextField` from wicket-extensions. And you could query the database (Hibernate, I suppose) for usernames directly instead of Users, instead of iterating the users list in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But with respect to Wicket, it does not make sense. In my situation where its a search page, and I have an object that represents each field of the search, startDate, endDate, username etc and I want a drop down of usernames, the choice I have is to either loop through all the users and create a list<String> or to assign a IModel<User> to dropdown and then extract that value into my search object. The whole idea of a select list is to shove the select option value, a string into the name of the select....Thanks again for the response, I would have never figured on my own

Comment: DropDownChoice lets theuser choose one object in a list. I think it makes sense that the property you use to set the chosen object is of the same type. If what you want is auto-complete of a text field, you could try DefaultCssAutocompleteTextField from wicket-extensions. And you could query the database (Hibernate, I suppose) for usernames directly instead of Users, instead of iterating the users list in memory.

Answer (score 0):

PropertyModel is good choice for such problems. Topic is an object and has a string name.I have override the toString() method in Topic to name and it is working properly.I suggest using this method.

```
topicDropDown = new DropDownChoice<Topic>("topicOptions", new PropertyModel<Topic>       (this.top, "topicOptions"), new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Topic>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Topic> load() {
            return top.getAllTopics();

        }
```